# Laptop battery calibration not working even after trying all the methods and bypasses win 10

Tags: windows, battery, power, charging, calibration

[image]

The image shows how fast the battery is wearing out. but then when I checked today it gave me about normal battery backup.

The discharging stops at 5.5% then it stays on for about 3 more hours on light usage. That's why I thought calibrating it again will solve things but no.

Things I tried:

1. disabled critical power actions then drained the battery fully then recharge.
2. uninstalled battery driver then drain it then recharge.
3. using acer software to recalibrate.

nothing working.

Comment: How old is the battery ? Have you tried another one ?

Comment: About 1 year old. Uh no I'vent tried putting another battery cause it still works...just the percentage of charge left shown is wrong and windows refuse to calibrate it.